# error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::pair<int, int>'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is my horrible attempt at a function that returns the mode (most common element) of an `int` array.

The error mentioned in the title is commented out in the code.

My understanding was that a `map` was made up of `pairs`, so I don't what the problem is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int mode(int* arrPtr, int size) { 
   assert (size > 0);
   std::map<int,int> M; 
   for (int k = 0; k < size; ++k) 
      M[*(arrPtr + k)]++;
   std::pair<int,int> maxpair(M.begin()->first, M.begin()->second);
   for (std::map<int,int>::iterator it = M.begin() + 1; it < M.end(); ++it) 
        if (it->second > maxpair->second) maxpair = *it; // ERROR HERE
   return maxpair->second;
} 


int main() { 

    int myArray[] = {1, 4, 5, 59, 1, -1, 4, 9, 1, 1, 9, -40};

    return 0;

}
```

Also, there's gotta be a better way to do this. How would a C++ guru do it?

Comment: `maxpair` isn't a pointer, so you can't use `->`.

Comment: *(arrPtr + k) == arrPtr[k], and the later is easier to read

Comment: Also, `std::pair<int,int> maxpair(M.begin()->first, M.begin()->second);` is simply `std::pair<int,int> maxpair(*arrPtr, 1);`

Comment: I don't see any reason to believe that the count of the first integer of arrPtr would be 1.

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
if (it->second > maxpair->second)
```

with:

```
if (it->second > maxpair.second)
```

If you take a look at your program, `maxpair` is of type `std::pair<int, int>` which [does not](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) have the `operator->` overloaded.

What you are trying to access, instead, is the member object `second`, therefore you should use `maxpair.second`.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator acts basically like a pointer which is why you use -> on it. Your std::pair however is a value, so you should use `.` instead of `->`.

Try:

```
if (it->second > maxpair.second) maxpair = *it;
```

P.S. The maxpair = *it assignment can be slow because of the overhead involved in copying an object. If you're going for speed it would probably be better to store the value and count as simple integers instead of as a pair object.

P.P.S. If you're trying to find the mode, don't you actually want the value that has the largest count, rather then the count?